# Why is Postgres sending network traffic on OSx

Tags: macos, networking, postgresql

I was looking through my Activity Monitor seeing if there was anything running that was hogging my network and noticed that Postgres has the largest amount of bytes sent.

[image]

Now the numbers aren't huge and I am positive this isn't the cause of my slow internet but I don't understand why Postgres would be going out over the network at all?

### Relevent Details

- OSx Yosemite with latest patches installed.
- postgres (PostgreSQL) 9.3.5

Answer (score 9):

The Activity Monitor captures local network traffic as well and it seems like Postgres has some statistic collection that runs locally.